# Counting the total XML-files in a directory

Tags: c#, .net

Im trying to write a program that counts the total amounts of XML-files that are in a directory and subdirectories. 
Here is how I tried:

```
namespace Jobbuppgift1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string path1 = "c:\\Jobbuppg";

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path1, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
            textBox1.Text = fileCount.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I get no error, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add extra slash to path1 otherwise "J" is being escaped or "@" works too

```
namespace Jobbuppgift1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string path1 = "c:\\Jobbuppg";//this or line below
    string path1 = @"c:\Jobbuppg";//this or line above

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path1, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        textBox1.Text = fileCount.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: are you sure your event is being invoked?